# MYSQL Loop Showing Extra "Empty" Result

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

I have deleted the table and started over with new data over and over and tried to figure out why my loop is adding an extra empty result at the beginning. The code that I am using for the loop is below.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `addresses` WHERE `company_name` = '$pro_company'";
    $query = $mysqli->query("$sql");    
        while($array[] = $query->fetch_object());
            array_pop($array);
            foreach($array as $listing) :
                echo $listing->Taddress . " ";
                echo $listing->Tcity. " ";
                echo $listing->Tstate . " ";
                echo $listing->Tzip . " ";
                echo " <a href='edit.php?pid=". $listing->PID . "'>edit</a> |";
                echo " <a href='delete.php?pid=". $listing->PID . "'>delete</a>";
                echo "</a><br />";
        endforeach;
```

The results I am getting from this loop are below.

```
       edit | delete
       14220 Parrott Ext. TestCity AL 84106 edit | delete
```

I am trying to learn mysqli statements so I am sure there is something I am missing.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The first row that the query is returning must have empty columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw a

```
print_r($array);die;
```

Before the foreach and look at the output. This should give you an idea of where exactly the problem is located.

Comment: I printed the array and found the issue. I was including another query from another page. Thanks a lot for your help! I changed my coding around and its working great now.

Comment: No problem! Learn to love print_r()! :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your database has a row with no values. Check that first. happens more often than you realise (to me anyway)

As a possible solution, you can add an extra condition before echo'ing to ensure a value exists

```
foreach($array as $listing) :
   if($listing->Taddress){
     echo $listing->Taddress . " ";
```

Personally, I'd find the cause first. print_r will help

Comment: I used your if statement in my loop and that seemed to make it work and cut out the extra entry. Thanks for your help!